# Create dataframe from grouped elements of a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I have a vector in R that looks like this:

```
vector = c('name1',100,'name2',101,'name3',102,'name4',103)
```

what i want to do is create a DF from this vector that looks like this:

```
+------------------+
|   User| Value    |
+------------------+
|  name1|     100  |
|  name2|     101  |
|  name3|     102  |
|  name4|     103  |
+------------------+
```

what would be the be the more efficient way to do so? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
vector = c('name1',100,'name2',101,'name3',102,'name4',103)

M <- t(matrix(vector, nrow = 2))
colnames(M) <- c("user", "value")
as.data.frame(M)
```